# notepad++ regex search replace in html tag

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

What I want is to replace:

```
<meta name="description" content="some content here">
```

to

```
<meta name="description" content="">
```

I hope it isn't to hard for notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. replace `content="[^"]*"` with `content=""`

see  screenshot[image]

Unless you specifically want the content attribute **only from meta tags**

Comment: @user3278890 Thank you for confirming. Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered

Answer (score 1):

Enable 'regular expressions' in replace dialog
and try searching for:

```
<meta name="description" content="[A-Za-z0-9].*">
```